# Comparing string with backslashes from db

Tags: asp.net, escaping

Hello, I have this string

```
string a="a\"
```

I need to compare it to a string from a database, but when i get this string from the database it returns with double slashes:

```
stringfromdb="a\\"
```

so the comparison fails:

```
if(a==stringfromdb){//do something}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the strings really contain backslashes? I'm asking because the backslashes seem to come from the representation in C# (for example `\ ` is represented as `"\\"` and `"` is represented as `"\""`).

Comment: probabily backslash is a visual studio/c# way to show special char, but the problem is it: i'have a runtime function that make an hash of a string: string hashedString hs= ComputeHash("1","1"), if i see it in visual studio debug, it is: e½CÙÊ¦à,™\v\n‚e-Ê, now if i select the same string from db and fill a datatable with dataadapter: select hashedpassword from users where userid='userwhitsalt1andpassword1' and whatch this datatable in visual  studio debugger i see it has doubled the backslash: e½CÙÊ¦à,™\\v\\n‚e-Ê and this makes the comparison to fail

Answer (score 1):

First you must figure out what you really want to compare. Since the strings are not equal, the comparison **should fail**.

Maybe you want to compare everything except the trailing backslashes? If that is the case, then use this:

```
if(a.TrimEnd('\\') == stringfromdb.TrimEnd('\\')){//do something}
```

But an even better idea might be to find out why those backslashes are added to the strings you insert into the database.

Comment: the problem is that i have a strng containg back slashes that i want to compare with the same string in db an hashed password e½CÙÊ¦à,™\v\n‚e-Ê now when i get this string from db it will be retourned with double back slash: e½CÙÊ¦à,™\\v\\n‚e-Ê and the comparison fails

Comment: sparrows81: I don't think the DBMS adds an extra backslash. I think the string you get is exactly what is inserted into the database to begin with. Anyways, the condition in the code in my answer should make it evaluate to true.